# Como ocultar las filas que tengan un STOCK = 0

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

Buenas tengo un problema que mi controlador me trae todas las filas de un DICTADO DE UN CURSO aun si este tenga CUPOS = 0. Estoy leyendo la documentacion de Laravel (Eloquent)  y vi que puedo usar lo siguiente el tema es que no se como hacer para no mostrar la fila que tenga cupos = 0.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

if (DB::table('dictations')->where('cupos', 0)->doesntExist())

Adjunto tambien una foto del controlador que usa esta plantilla .blade.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Encontre la solucion me parecio raro la sintaxis pero anda.

```
 public function show(Course $course)
{
    //whith uso para relacionar mi tabla dictation con mi Tabla Courses       
    $dictations = Dictation::with('courses')->where('stock', '>', 0)
                            ->orderby('date', 'DESC')
                            ->get();

    return view('courses.show', compact( 'course', 'dictations'));

}
```

Comment: la parte de where('stock' '>', 0)